# Blank Page in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, facelets

If my code throws an exception, sometimes - not everytime - the jsf presents a blank page. I´m using facelets for layout.
A similar error were reported at this [Sun forumn´s post](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?messageID=10237827), but without answers.
Anyone else with the same problem, or have a solution?
;)

Due to some requests. Here follow more datails:

web.xml

```
 <error-page>
        <exception-type>com.company.ApplicationResourceException</exception-type>
        <location>/error.faces</location>
 </error-page>
```

And the stack related to jsf is printed after the real exception:

```
####<Sep 23, 2008 5:42:55 PM GMT-03:00> <Error> <HTTP> <comp141> <AdminServer> <[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'> <<WLS Kernel>> <> <> <1222202575662> <BEA-101107> <[weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext@6d46b9 - appName: 'ControlPanelEAR', name: 'ControlPanelWeb', context-path: '/Web'] Problem occurred while serving the error page.
javax.servlet.ServletException: viewId:/error.xhtml - View /error.xhtml could not be restored.
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:249)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:283)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:175)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.invokeServlet(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:525)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherImpl.forward(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:261)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ForwardAction.run(ForwardAction.java:22)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ErrorManager.handleException(ErrorManager.java:144)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.handleThrowableFromInvocation(WebAppServletContext.java:2201)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2053)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1366)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:200)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:172)
javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/error.xhtml - View /error.xhtml could not be restored.
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:248)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:117)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:226)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:124)
```

I´m using the jsf version `Mojarra 1.2_09`, `richfaces 3.2.1.GA` and  `facelets 1.1.13`.

Hope some help :(

Comment: Would you mind giving us a little more detail? What implementation you're using and how is your error handling system configured.

Comment: I re-edited this issue. Please take a look.
;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this largely depends on your JSF implementation. I've heard that some will render blank screens.

The one we were using would throw error 500's with a stack trace. Other times out buttons wouldn't work without any error for the user. This was all during our development phase.

But the best advice I can give you is to catch the exceptions and log them in an error log so you have the stack trace for debugging later. For messages that we couldn't do anything about like a backend failing we would just add a fatal message to the FacesContext that gets displayed on the screen and log the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually it´s sad. Nice recommendation that we are already following, but the problem still goes.

The point is exactly catch whatever to avoid this behavior. :(
Thanks.

Comment: well i have seen in my application where sometimes page was loaded blank.the cause was found to be as too many files were being open in my application in bg activities and the file streams were not being closed in some places.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed a similar problem in my `error.jsp` page today.  This won't be exactly the same as yours, but it might point someone in the right direction if they're having a similar problem.  My problem seemed to be coming from two different sources.

First, the `message` exception property wasn't being set in some of the servlets that were throwing exceptions caught by the error page.  The servlets were catching and rethrowing exceptions using the [`ServletException(Throwable rootCause)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletException.html#ServletException%28java.lang.Throwable%29) constructor.

Second, in the error page itself, the original author had used scriptlet code to parse the message using `String.split(message, ";");`  Since the message was `null` this failed.  I was getting a `NullPointerException` in my error log, along with the message "Problem occurred while serving the error page."

These two things combined to give me a blank page at the URL of the servlet that was throwing the original exception.  I fixed my problem by providing my own error message when I rethrow exceptions in my servlets using the [`ServletException(String message, Throwable rootCause)`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletException.html#ServletException%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) constructor, so the error message will no longer be `null`.  I also rewrote the `error.jsp` page using EL instead of scriptlet code, but that wasn't strictly necessary.

Answer (score -1):

For a blank page on JSF 2, place a breakpoint in `ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle` or a class overriding this method. In my case it was due to custom code which was a too restrictive and the error was not logged.

Comment: I wrote this for people landing here after a search, in 2012 they may be using JSF 2. This is why I specified it applies to JSF 2. But anyways thanks for the downvote...